# Regulator output voltage drop in high temperature

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

We have used EN6360QI regulator in one of  our designs and found a voltage drop at the output during the high-temperature test (at 60 degrees Celsius.) The voltage gradually decreases to 0.3V from 1V as shown below.

[image]

We have tried without connecting any load to it but the behavior is the same as shown in the above image.
Could someone please tell us what causes this?

Comment: One piece doing this? Maybe a faulty component (shorted capacitor, for example) or a faulty solder joint. Intermittent faults are frequently temperature-sensitive.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany we have observed this issue in multiple boards. The issue is unique in all the boards.

Comment: @Chitharanjan You mentioned testing this without a load. I've not looked, but is there a minimum load for this converter? Or does it work both CCM and DCM? Is the source of the IC reliable?

Comment: `gradually decreases` within less than 1 ms.

Comment: @periblepsis we observed the source of the IC is constant 5V, there is no fluctuation on it. I have also not seen the CCM and DCM mode in EN6360QI datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

The EN6360QI regulator itself [is rated for 85 °C](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/en6360qi/intel), so that should not be an issue **if these are genuine EN6360QI parts**.

Some things to consider:

- Is the supply voltage within spec's (2.5 - 6 VDC)?
- Are associated capacitors within tolerance at 60 °C for value and leakage?
- Have you tried substituting the EN6360QI with one from another supplier?

Comment: 1) Yes it's within spec i.e 5V 2) The components associated with ii used in the design are rated to operate at -55c to 125c basically automotive grade 3) Currently, this part is obsolete and we ordered from digikey when this part was enough stock